# How does cnosdb convert the current time directly into a timestamp

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

How does cnosdb convert the current time directly into a timestamp
I get the time as follows

```sql
select now();
+-----------------------------+
| now()                       |
+-----------------------------+
| 2023-05-15T07:20:55.265027Z |
+-----------------------------+
Query took 0.005 seconds.
```

But I want to get the timestamp directly.how can i get it？

Comment: I don't see any Rust code in this question: do you want to programmatically (from Rust) obtain the timestamp? If yes, which client library do you use; if not, then the [tag:rust] tag is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I added it mainly because the programming language of this db is rust. I will re-edit the question and untag the rust.

Answer (score 1):

Later, I checked some information and found that the data can be changed to timestamp in this way：

```
public ❯ select cast(now()as bigint);
+---------------------+
| now()               |
+---------------------+
| 1684290575284788126 |
+---------------------+
Query took 0.002 seconds.
```